# How to avoid hitting REST Authentication API everytime to consume actual Service

Tags: java, rest, authentication

I need to consume rest api services n number of times
I will have to login each time programatically through Java URL Authentication to consume the actual Service
My Application will make n number of calls to the API and i do not feel to hit the authentication URL everytime to consume the actual service
How can i login once and maintain some time to consume the services n number of times through different HTTP requests?
Sometimes i am getting Connection Timeout as i am frequently hitting authentication URL

Comment: How about using a login token that expires after a defined amount of time?

Comment: What is the authentication method? Is it stateless? dose it support Basic Authentication? OAuth1? Or use a cookie to store session ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not your API, there is probably nothing you can do.

However, most REST APIs that require authentication will give you some kind of authentication token (and a refresh token that can be used to renew it after it expires) - you send this token as a header on all of your calls to the API - if a call comes back as unauthorized, you send the refresh token and are returned a new auth token, without ever having to ask the user for their credentials again.

If you need to implement something like this yourself (on an API you have control over), I recommend using something like JSON Web Tokens (JWT).

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is a basic authentication and a third party REST service. I am calling these Services in the Third Party end, My WAR will pass the message through Kafka and the same will invoke REST call through SpringBoot running in the Third party end. It is a stateless calls that happens n number of times from my end. Managing and storing the session(login) in the Thirdparty end is really tough. Hence i raised this question

Comment: Can anyone pls see the comment i added